# Matlab compatibility? What is wrong?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, plot, version, runtime-error

I'm using a Matlab code for data analysis (fitting of scattering data), which is written in 2006. This code works with Matlab 2007 well, but at least it doesn't work in Matlab 2009 and newer versions. Therefore I think it is caused by some changes in the runtime environment concerning how to act with GUIs.

In following I post the error message I always get:

**Illegal right hand side in assignment. Too many elements.**

`Error in Frontend>do_fit (line 749)
                               [handles.fitfunctions{fitfunction_index}.param_vector,
        handles.data_fit, exitflag, output] = ...`

`Error in Frontend>fit_button_Callback (line 673)
     do_fit(hObject, handles);`

`Error in gui_mainfcn (line 96)
        feval(varargin{:});`

`Error in Frontend (line 42)
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});`

`Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback`

Lines 747 to 750 in my function "do_fit" in frontend.m look like:

```
fitmethods = Fit();

fitmethod = fitmethods{2}.func; 

[handles.fitfunctions{fitfunction_index}.param_vector, handles.data_fit,        
exitflag, output] = ...fitmethod((@(A,z)fitfunction(const,A,z)), fitparams, xdata, 
ydata, lb_vector, ub_vector, weightdata ,options);
```

I would be very thankful, if someone has an idea what is wrong in this piece of code!

Comment: What is fitmethod returning?

Comment: It look like the input/output of the function have change.

Comment: Just run it with `dbstop if error` and carefully compare the expected input arguments with the actual input arguments.